# Matlab: Remove loop from code

Tags: arrays, matlab, multidimensional-array, vectorization

`flow` is a 4D double matrix whose fourth dimension is always `2`. I want to implement this loop without using loops.

Essentially , For each index in the third dimension,, I want to divide `flow1` into square blocks of size `block-size`, then calculate the mean of the values in fourth dimension of each block, then assign those values back to the respective fourth dimension for the  all the elements in that block .

Typical values are `[height width N block_size] = [ 480  640 100 8]` . It is guaranteed that `block_size` is a factor of both `height` and `width`

```
[height,width,N,~]  = size(flow1);
reduced_flow = zeros(size(flow1));
for ii = 1:block_size:height
    for jj = 1:block_size:width
        for k = 1:N
            reduced_flow(ii:ii+block_size-1,jj:jj+block_size-1,k,1) = mean(mean(flow1(ii:ii+block_size-1,jj:jj+block_size-1,k,1),1),2);
            reduced_flow(ii:ii+block_size-1,jj:jj+block_size-1,k,2) = mean(mean(flow1(ii:ii+block_size-1,jj:jj+block_size-1,k,2),1),2);
        end
    end
end
```

**Example**

```
 flow1 = round(10*rand(4,4,2,2));
 block_size = 2;
 [flow1 reduced_flow]

 ans(:,:,1,1) =

     6.0000    4.0000    1.0000         0    4.0000    4.0000    2.2500    2.2500
     6.0000         0    2.0000    6.0000    4.0000    4.0000    2.2500    2.2500
          0    5.0000    1.0000    3.0000    3.2500    3.2500    2.7500    2.7500
     6.0000    2.0000    2.0000    5.0000    3.2500    3.2500    2.7500    2.7500


 ans(:,:,2,1) =

     7.0000    1.0000    3.0000    4.0000    4.5000    4.5000    2.7500    2.7500
     5.0000    5.0000    2.0000    2.0000    4.5000    4.5000    2.7500    2.7500
     5.0000    9.0000    6.0000    9.0000    6.7500    6.7500    5.5000    5.5000
     4.0000    9.0000    6.0000    1.0000    6.7500    6.7500    5.5000    5.5000


 ans(:,:,1,2) =

     1.0000    9.0000    7.0000    5.0000    3.2500    3.2500    7.5000    7.5000
     2.0000    1.0000   10.0000    8.0000    3.2500    3.2500    7.5000    7.5000
     7.0000   10.0000    3.0000    8.0000    6.2500    6.2500    4.0000    4.0000
     3.0000    5.0000    4.0000    1.0000    6.2500    6.2500    4.0000    4.0000


 ans(:,:,2,2) =

     2.0000    3.0000    7.0000    7.0000    2.7500    2.7500    6.5000    6.5000
     4.0000    2.0000    5.0000    7.0000    2.7500    2.7500    6.5000    6.5000
     1.0000    2.0000    9.0000    6.0000    4.2500    4.2500    4.5000    4.5000
     5.0000    9.0000    1.0000    2.0000    4.2500    4.2500    4.5000    4.5000
```

Comment: It would be better if you explained what the code does

Comment: @LuisMendo Sorry,I will do it know, something came up so I had to go

Comment: So following your ideas above you want to take a submatrix in the first 2 dimension `[480, 640]` and then calculate the mean in 4th dimension `[8]` ignoring the 3rd dimension `[100]`? That mean value you want to assign to all those values in 4th-dimension. What should happen with the 3rd-dimension? Ignore it, delete it? And am I understanding your question right?

Comment: @TheMinion Your question is clear to me , I have edited the explanation.

Comment: I guess you are working at it right now, but in that example what answer would you expect for what kind of `block-size`?

Comment: I have put all the details in the example, `block_size = 2` and `flow and reduced_flow` have been concatenated for ease of comparison

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Approach 1

```
flow11 = reshape(flow1,size(flow1,1),[]);
fun = @(block_struct) mean2(block_struct.data);
mat1 = blockproc(flow11,[block_size block_size],fun);
mat2 = imresize(mat1,block_size ,'nearest');
reduced_flow = reshape(mat2,size(flow1));
```

Approach 2

```
t1 = sum(reshape(sum(reshape(flow1,block_size,[])),height/block_size,block_size,[]),2)./block_size^2;
t2 = reshape(t1,1,1,[]);
t3 = t2(ones(1,block_size),ones(1,block_size),:,:);
t4 = reshape(permute(t3,[1 3 2]),size(t3,1)*size(t3,3),[]);
out = permute(reshape(t4,height,size(t4,1)/height,[]),[1 3 2]);
reduced_flow = reshape(out,size(flow1));
```

Comment: For ``size(flow) = [480 640 51 2]``  execution time increased fro 105 sec(loop) to 216 sec(you code). Also , ``b = reduced_flow_loop ~= reduced_flow_divakar ;error =  sum(b(:)) `` gives ``error as 3788608``

Comment: @Nishant Check out the just added Approach 2.

Comment: @Nishant If you are doing error checking for `rand` values, I would suggest using max of differences to avoid floating point calculation issues, like this - `err1 = reduced_flow(:) - reduced_flow2(:);max_error = max(err1(:))
`

Comment: can I do this if size of flow1 is [ 480 640 100 1]

Comment: @Nishant Did you try with that size? Also, I am curious if you are getting any speedups with this approach?

Comment: This took no time, I mean output came almost when I pressed enter , so I didn't profiled the code.with that size I tried , got considerable error between values generated by loop and your code, I don't have the actual value of error right know